# Android google map icon marker with just color white

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

im using google maps in my android project, and im having a problem.

my icon does not show the correct color of the image, just a white icon

i take a screenshot of the app
[image]
the map icon is in center of screen...

the original color is yellow, but only show a white.

follow the code

```
  googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .title(lista.get(i).getNome())
                                        .snippet("")
                                        .position(lista.get(i).getLatLng())
                                        .alpha(lista.get(i).getId())                                    
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_mapaok1))                          

                        );
```

ANyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android from Lollipop version doesn't support any icon format. It changes it to white as the background of the image is white and it is not in the form of silhouette icon, hence they are appearing white.

Refer to the following links to create an icon:

http://appicontemplate.com/android-product-icons/

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/07/making-beautiful-android-app-icons.html

Comment: i've tested in jellybean and it worked...i ll try to follow this links and if work i'll mark this answer as correct

Comment: I followed the tutorials that you went and did not work.

I downloaded the template icons, and again did not work out .... did a test with just a square in yellow and white keeps popping up.

you have some other solution?

Comment: @reemy Did you used the Silhouette Image Icon?

Comment: Use thos link to know and create about Silhouette
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/photoshop-create-quick-silhouettes/

Comment: I just 've downloaded the template and put my logo .
will i have to do it again using this sihoulete tool?

Comment: i did the logo again and dont work...only appears a white mark...any other suggestion? build.version cant work?

Comment: Change the background and you can see the image. Please try to learn what is Silhouette image is actually. You will get your answer.

Silhouette Images are supported by all the versions. especially Lollipop and above.